# ggplot in r shiny from csv file

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am a newbie in r shiny, what I am trying to do a ggplot in r shiny from a file of my local computer. But it gives me error
Warning: Error in as.character: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
[No stack trace available]

I am not sure what is going wrong, my df data is basically a csv file with three variables(year, variable and value). Our variable 'variable' is character vector(each element involves multiple words) that I am not sure how to convert into string vector(even I don't know either possible or not, but I tried toString, is.string etc). So any help would be really appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
df<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\syeda\\Documents\\syeda_demo\\7.2.21_demo\\vis.csv")
# define user interface object
ui <- fluidPage(
  (inputId = df),
  (outputId = ggplot))


# define server() function
server <- function(input, output){
  output$myoutput <- render({
    ggplot(df, aes(x=year(), y=value(), fill=variable())) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ylab("proportion") + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = paste0(alphabet(20), "FF"), name = "year") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  input$df
    # If it uses an input value (input$myinput),
    # the output will be rebuilt whenever
    # the input value changes
  })}

# call to shinyApp() which returns the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that syntax for the UI, but you need to use function like `textInput()` and `plotOutput()`. You can't just put IDs in parenthesis. And then it's not clear where values like `aes(x=year(), y=value(), fill=variable())` are meant to come from. Normally you get those from inputs like `input$year` or something. If you are new to shiny, maybe check out the talks here: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/ especially the ones on Reactivity.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the link, I am trying to learn it from the past few days and it seems very different than r-studio(thought it would be similar) as it is an app. Can you give me template what you have just told. And, aes(x=year(), y=value(), fill=variable()) probably should write as aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable). It's the thing I did in my r-studio and it works fine.